# Loop through array of files in folder

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm making a RPG, and would like to load dialog .json separated by folders by Levels. Each Level folder has all quest dialog .json, even if it's not completed by the player yet.

Folder structure:

[image]

I send an array with the quests the player has completed (boxed in red above):

`jsonFilesArray = ["101", "102", "103", "104", "201"];`

`allLevelsArray = [1, 2]`

I would like to loop through dynamically the `Levels` folders and look only for the quest numbers that have been completed (in `jsonFilesArray`).

The way this code works is, it keeps looping through all levels, searching for a file that may not be in its folder. (ex: when it loops through Level 2 folder, it won't find `quest_101.json`, so it breaks).

```
$.each(allLevelsArray, function (i, levelNum) { 
    $.each(jsonFilesArray, function (i, jsonQuestID) {  
        $.getJSON("dialog/Level "+levelNum+"/quest_"+jsonQuestID+".json", function(json) {
            //do stuff 
        });
    });
});
```

**How** can I dynamically loop through all Level folders searching for only the quests given in `jsonFilesArray`? I'd prefer not to even worry about looping through the Levels folders.

Thanks

Comment: flatten them all into one folder/array, then search that. given the file naming pattern, you shouldn't have any name conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why even have an allLevelsArray if you're storing the level in your jsonFilesArray anyway?

Why not structure your array like so:

```
jsonFilesArray = ["1-01", "1-02", "1-03", "1-04", "2-01"];
```

And then loop like this:

```
$.each(jsonFilesArray, function (i, jsonQuestID) {
    var level = jsonQuestID.slice(0, jsonQuestID.indexOf('-'));
    var quest = jsonQuestID.slice(jsqonQuestID.indexOf('-') + 1);
    $.getJSON("dialog/Level "+ level +"/quest_"+ (level + quest) +".json", function(json) {
        //do stuff 
    });
});
```

Or if you keep all the files in the same folder (which is completely doable considering your naming convention), and assuming your original array:

```
$.each(jsonFilesArray, function (i, jsonQuestID) {
    $.getJSON("dialog/quest_"+ jsonQuestID +".json", function(json) {
        //do stuff 
    });
});
```

If there is anything specific you need to do for each level iteration, I'd suggest either a two dimensional array or an array of objects:

```
jsonFilesArray = [{level: 1, quests: ["01", "02", "03", "04"]}, {level: 2, quests: ["01"]}];
```

```
$.each(jsonFilesArray, function (i, levelObj) {
    //do stuff with level
    $.each(levelObj.quests, function (i, quest) {
        $.getJSON("dialog/quest_"+ (levelObj.level + quest) +".json", function(json) {
            //do stuff 
        });
    });
});
```